# Issue with carriage return in my php mail

Tags: php

I'm learning PHP langage and I'm getting an issue with my .langs file and my php mail part.

The part according to mail message looks like this :

```
$message = $outputlangs->transnoentities("ExpenseReportWaitingForApprovalMessage", $expediteur->getFullName($langs), get_date_range($object->date_debut,$object->date_fin,'',$langs), $link);
```

And I have in my .langs file :

> ExpenseReportWaitingForApprovalMessage=Une nouvelle note de frais est
>   en attente d'approbation sur notre ERP.\n-
>   Utilisateur : %s\n- Période : %s\nCliquez ici pour afficher la note de
>   frais: %s.

When I send my email, I get this :

[image]

My carriage returns don't work and I don't find a way to solve this problem.

I tried :

```
$message = $outputlangs->trans
```

But none effect.

Do you have any idea ?

Thank you

**EDIT :**

I tried to remove text from .langs file and I wrote this :

```
$corps = "Une nouvelle note de frais est en attente d'approbation sur notre ERP.\r\n- Utilisateur : %s\r\n- Période : %s\r\nCliquez ici pour afficher la note de frais: %s.";
$message = ($corps, $expediteur->getFullName($langs), get_date_range($object->date_debut,$object->date_fin,'',$langs), $link);
```

But I'm getting blank page

Comment: it's probably set in single quotes `'\n'`, as opposed to double quotes `"\n"`. Hard to say by what your code really does, but that's my assumption. That, or you're trying to send as html instead of plain text.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you for your answer. I tried `\n`, `'\n'` and `"\n"` but my issue still there. Hum I don't really know which is the exact process to send email with php mail

Comment: Try this - "\r\n"

Comment: Welcome. If you intend on using php's `mail()`, have a look through the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php @Deadpool

Comment: what OS is this running under also? @Deadpool you can try PHP_EOL as a cross-platform method.

Comment: @QuackHead Doesn't work too

Comment: @Fred-ii- I assume it's php's `mail()` so I have to take a look to the manual. It's a linux OS

Comment: Maybe I have to remove variable from langs and write this variable directly in my php file with carriage returns ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I see the issue. Maybe (?) I do not recognize whatever transnoentities is. You didn't include it.

But, If you have just this `\n` as a literal in your langs file that is getting stuffed into $message... it is just going to transfer that straight into the mail body for face value.

You need to actually have real newlines in your langs file... not string literals of them.

Try doing:

```
$message = str_replace('\n',"\n",$message);
```

Do this before sending to mail. (and yes, the first value in `str_replace` is meant to be single quotes to replace the literal with the actual).

In your second edit about this:

```
$corps = "Une nouvelle note de frais est en attente d'approbation sur notre ERP.\r\n- Utilisateur : %s\r\n- Période : %s\r\nCliquez ici pour afficher la note de frais: %s.";
$message = ($corps, $expediteur->getFullName($langs), get_date_range($object->date_debut,$object->date_fin,'',$langs), $link);
```

I think this is a big syntax error. Unless I'm misunderstanding your assignment. Turn on php errors and debug your script:

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Thank you with your answer ! You solved my issue with your `str_replace`. It seems to work now ;) However, I don't really know what syntax error I have in my edit (I'm a beginner with php).

Comment: Yeah, `$message = ($var , $var , $var);` doesn't look like correct syntax, and wasn't sure what you were attempting. But that throws a parse error when you turn on full warnings in php.